# rdf:type in Jena API for SPARQL not working?

Tags: sparql, jena

Why Jena API (Java) for SPARQL does not provide any result for queries with `rdf:type`? Other SPARQL queries work just fine. For example, this query is not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p{
    ?p rdf:type :AAA
}
```

Full code:

```
String queryString=listOfPrefixesOntNormXML+" \n"
                   +"SELECT DISTINCT ?p{ ?p rdf:type :AAA }";
System.out.println(queryString);

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString); 
           QueryExecution qExe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( "http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query );
           ResultSet results = qExe.execSelect();
           ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;
```

Full queryString:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX owl11: <http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl11#> 
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#> 
PREFIX owl11xml: <http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl11-xml#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?p{ ?p rdf:type :AAA }
```

Comment: Check the prefix declaration for `rdf:` and for `:`.

Comment: It is correct, please see the full code and output above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are posing a query to DBpedia endpoint looking for an `rdf:type` of `:AAA` which doesn't exist.

If you change it to `dbo:Book`, it should work, because `rdf:type` exists in DBpedia!

Comment: I see now... my mistake

Comment: `dbo:book` -> `dbo:Book`